# Orthogonalizing a Gaussian Basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, quantum-states

Given a discrete Gaussian basis $$G = \{\lvert n\rangle, n \in \mathbb{Z}\},$$ where 
$$\langle x\rvert n \rangle = \exp\left(\dfrac{-(x-nL)^2}{2}\right),$$ with $L$ fixed.

Does there exist a set of functions $$\{f_{n}: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}, \vert f_n(x)\vert = 1, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ such that

$$A\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \langle n' \rvert x \rangle
\langle x\rvert n \rangle \overline{f_{n'}}(x) f_n(x) dx = \delta_{n, n'}~ ?$$

($A$ is a normalization factor and $\delta_{n'n}$ is the Kronecker Delta)

In other words, is it possible to create an orthogonal basis such that the modulus of its elements $(\vert \langle x \vert n \rangle \vert)$ are Gaussian functions?

The farthest I got until now was to observe that chosing 
$f_n(x) = \exp{(i\omega nLx)}$, the integral above results in a gaussian over $\omega$ for different $n, n'$.

Comment: I am misunderstanding your interesting question. It seems like by definition the states ${|n\rangle}$ are the eigenstates of the operator $\hat{f}$. But since $\langle n'|n\rangle\neq 0$, the operator $\hat{f}$ is not diagonal in the basis ${|n\rangle}$ which is a contradiction. In other words, since there shouldn't exist an operator whose eigenstates are non-orthogonal, the postulate of such an operator $\hat{f}$ is problematic. Kindly correct me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I believe my clumsy notation may be at fault. For me $f_n$ is just a function of $x$. So in equation what I mean by $f_{n'}^\dagger$ inside the integral is the complex conjugate of the function $f_{n'}$ calculated at the point x. What I am proposing is to consider the transformation $ \langle x \vert n \rangle \to f_n(x) \langle x \vert n \rangle$, which I want to be orthogonal to $ \langle x \vert n' \rangle \to f_{n'}(x) \langle x \vert n' \rangle$. I will make the necessary adjustments to make this more clear. Does this answer your doubts?

Comment: *A* is 1/$\sqrt{\pi}$ so can be taken to the right. Have you moved on to complex Gaussians? Why don't you write down the general eqn whose solutions you are seeking?

Comment: Yes, $A$ would have that value if $f_n(x) =1 \forall x $, but notice that this $f$ does not satisfy the last equation, because it does not make the functions orthognal for different n (two different Gaussians are not orthogonal). The general equation I want to satisfy is the last one, with the constraint $\vert f_n(x)\vert =1$. About complex Gaussians, I'm not sure what you mean by it. If you mean a function whose modulus is a Gaussian in $x$, then yes. If you mean a complex Normal distribution, then no, because our wave function is a function from real space to complex space.

Comment: I a not sure what you are saying. *Define* $f_n(x)=\exp (i\omega_n (x))$ and try to find solutions of the eqn for functions ω(x) of different indices. For identical indices, you've already solved it , and I tried to get *A* out of your way, since you are rushing to throw all pots on the fire and hyper-formalize.